# WebService call works from WinForms app but not from WebApp

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, endpoint

I am trying to call a webservice to get information about specific objects. It works perfectly fine in my test WinForms application, basically after I added the service reference I did not have to do anything else than creating a local client in my C# class, setting up the input parameters and calling the method that was in the documentation and I received the response I wanted. Very simple webservive, no https, no magic.

I copied my code to my MVC web application, I made sure to copy EXACTLY the same url, web.config settings (bindings, endpoints), I even updated the service reference many times, but in MVC it does not work. The error message says:

"There was no endpoint listening at 'webservicename' that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

The inner exception is:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888"

I have set up my hosts file, because I am using Local IIS and wanted to use the websie's name in the url, so I have this in my hosts:

"127.0.0.1 www.mywebsite.local"

I have a feeling that either my firewall or app pool setting causes this problem, but I could not figure out which one. Once again, the webservice is working perfectly fine from my basic test WinForms app.

I tried to change the Identity of my app pool to something else than ApplicationPoolIdentity (I tried NetworkService, LocalService, LocalSystem), but it did not help.

.Net version is 4.5 in WinForms and 4.5.1 in MVC.

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

It looks like there is a problem with the proxy settings. In the MVC web.config I had the following section:
   `<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
    </defaultProxy>`

I do not know why, but when I set it to false, the problem goes away...I am not an expert of proxies. Does it mean I have to add special settings to my firewall?

Comment: What is the address of the webservice, and why did you need to tweak the `hosts` file?

Comment: I had to change the host file because I wanted to use www.mywebsite.local instead of localhost.
The webservice is a 3rd party service our company is paying for, so we have a licence key that we use to get data back for different items.

Comment: Then why are you trying to connect to the 3rd party webservice on 12.0.0.1 when that is the address of your own website? Shouldn't you connect to the actual 3rd party webservice url?

Comment: I have edited my question. There is a proxy settings in the web.config that causes this issue I think.